# how to handle backend credentional in wso2 api manager?

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I am using wso2 apimanager 3.2.0 and I am going to design some rest service that use my backend service. this backend service has basic authentication, so how to invoke and handle it in apim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define endpoint security when you are developing the API the Endpoints section of the API in the Publisher portal.

For more information, see [documentation](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/learn/design-api/endpoints/endpoint-security/basic-auth/#secure-endpoint-with-basic-auth).